# Breeze registerEntityTypeCtor not calling initializer

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I'm going through John Papa's HotTowel tutorial and adapting it to my own data.  I want to format a datetime field named startTime into a string formatted with moment, but the initializer function isn't even getting called to add the computed field.

in datacontext.js:

```
 var getSessions = function (sessionsObservable) {

    var query = EntityQuery.from('Sessions').orderBy('startTime', 'title');
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceded).fail(breezeQueryFailed);

    function querySucceded(data) {
        if (sessionsObservable) {
            sessionsObservable(data.results);
        }
        log('Retrieved Sessions', data, true);
    }
};



function configureBreezeManager() {
    breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
    var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(config.remoteServiceName);
    model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);
    return mgr;
}
```

in model.js:

```
    function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Sessions', null, sessionInitializer);
}


function sessionInitializer(session) {
    session.startDayTime = ko.computed(function () {
        var start = session.startTime();
        return start ? moment.utc(start).format('dddd h:mm a') : '';
    });
}
```

It returns all the data pulled from my API, but doesn't add that startDayTime computed field.  I put a breakpoint in sessionInitializer() function and it doesn't even get to it.  What am I missing?  Did updating to Breeze 1.4.4 change the way this is supposed to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it isn't getting called?  Change '' to 'doh' and see if that value updates.  If it is not console.log(session.startTime()); and make sure it has a value and isn't faulting out there

Comment: I have tried that and still nothing, and I put a breakpoint in it and it never breaks, so I'm pretty sure it's not getting called.  The console does show a value for startTime.  I'm actually checking for that server-side to make sure all records have a valid startTime or they're not even included in the API data.

Comment: Ok well here is the bigger question - why put formatting logic into an extra observable property?  If you are using moment and knockout that logic belongs in a custom binding handler wherever you are displaying the date.

Comment: True, and it works fine just formatting it on the view binding.  But, I still want to know why it's not calling the initializer function in case I want to create some computed values to sort and filter on or something.

Comment: My best guess is that it either is being called and is failing, you aren't correctly setting the sessions type, or startTime isn't properly set to work with Moment.js for some reason.  The code you are showing is not where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you registered the entity type as 'Sessions' (plural) instead of 'Session' (singular). It should be:

```
 metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Session', null, sessionInitializer);
```

'Session' (singular) is the name of the entity type. You create a new one with a line like

```
var newSession = mgr.createEntity('Session');
```

'Sessions' (plural) is the Web API query resource name that you target when retrieving Session entities.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Sessions');
```

It's easy to confuse the two. Sorry.

FWIW, as written, your metadataStore thinks it has both a 'Session' entity type and a 'Sessions' entity type.

Comment: I changed 'Sessions' to 'Session' in the registerEntityTypeCtor() and it's still not working.  Do I need to create a new entity?

Comment: That should have done it. Are your sure you revised the registration as shown? Check the browser cache to make sure you're changes are reflected. Check that the entity name really is "Session". Finally, set some breakpoints. After you register, `metadataStore._ctorRegistry.Session` should have hold your `initFn`. Break after the first query, get the metadataStore, and confirm that the 'Session' entity is in that store.

Comment: I've basically given up on the initializer and now I'm formatting it on the view, but now moment is throwing an error because it seems like something else is formatting it before it gets to the view.  When I just bind it with `data-bind="text: startTime"` it's displaying it like `Wed Jan 08 2014 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` rather than `2013-09-28T09:00:00`.  Is that something Breeze is doing because it sees it's a datetime field in the metadata?  I had this working yesterday, but then "undefined" started displaying instead of dates and I don't know what I did to cause that.

Comment: Breeze does not format datetime. When dates arrive from the server and they lack a timezone, Breeze adds 'z' (GMT) to keep Chrome and FF happy. That's it. I realize you're having a tough time, Josh. But we are at a loss to help given the information you've provided which contradicts everything we know to be working for the rest of us. Some important details are missing. You're going to have to create a tiny tiny repro of these problems and put it where we can reach it (e.g. GitHub). Sorry.